# Character check in file always returns true

Tags: c++, file, char

I've been banging my head trying to figure this one out. I would love to have a couple of you have a crack at it because I'm all out of ideas.

```
bool characterGetCFG1(string typeOverLoad, string var_name, string full_text) {
int pos = full_text.rfind(var_name) + var_name.length() + 1;
char character = full_text.at(pos);
if (character == 't' || 'T') {
    cout << full_text << "\n";
    cout << "features.assigned, " << var_name << ", " << full_text.at(pos) << ".\n";
    cout << "returned true \n";
    cout << character << "\n";
    return true;
}else{
    cout << "returned false \n";
    return false;
}

void setconfig(glow_t passed_glow) {
ifstream file;

file.open("config.cfg");
if (!file.is_open()) {
    exit(-10);
}
std::string raw;
while (file.good()) {
    raw.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    file >> raw;
}
file.close();

feats.setGlow(characterGetCFG1("t", "glow", raw));
```

Don't worry about the brackets I have the correct amount in project, I coulnd't fit them all in the code tag sadly.

EDIT: I forgot to incldue the 'config.cfg' file here ya go below.

> glow=false

Comment: `character == 't' || 'T'` will always be true because `'T'` is always true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(character == 't' || 'T')
```

Always evaluates to true, becase `'T'` always evaluates to true.  You probably intended to write `if (character == 't' || character == 'T')`

Comment: Wow thank you so much! Right on the money my man. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
character == 't' || character == 'T'
```

This:

```
character == 't' || 'T'
```

is the same as

```
(character == 't') || ('T' != 0)
```

which is always true because of the `'T'` on the right hand side.